# Linux moving or copying multiple files with a shell

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to copy all files with a .txt extensions into a new folder but I am unsure of how to do this with one command. Right now I am just typing:

cp file1 file2 file3 /Folder

but I think there is a better way since the ending is the same for all? Also is there a way to copy a group of .txt files and add to their name? For instance if I want to append .backup to all of the files but keep them in the same directory?

For instance file.txt would be copied and renamed to file.txt.backup (would work for multiple files of same .txt extension)

Comment: cp *txt /Folder

Comment: To copy all files with a .txt extensions into a new folder, use command cp,

`cp -r *.txt /new_folder_path`

Comment: and to create backup of them in the same directory use mv                                                     

     `mv *.txt *.txt.bk`

Comment: @SyedSaadAhmed - no, that's not how `mv` works.

Comment: You can use a wildcard to select. Adding the trailing / to the last argument ensures that you don't accidentally write them all to the same file, but cp is less stupid than it used to be. If you want to do it recursively for a particular file extension it is a little messier - and even more so if you want to recreate the folder structure - you may want to look at the find command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `cp *.txt /dest/dir/`?

And for adding `.backup` you could also do a loop that could look like this:

```
for i in *.txt
do
    cp "$i" "/dest/dir/$i.backup"
done
```

Comment: @Alfe Are double quotes really necessary? It didn't seem to me.

Comment: Yes, for files with spaces in their names.   Often forgotten.  Try this: `date > 'a b.txt'; for i in *.txt; do cp $i ./wherever/; done`.  This will raise an error as it tries to copy a file named `a` instead of `a b.txt`.

Comment: @Alfe Oh! Indeed, my bad. Thanks for the edit then, now that sounds really relevant.

Comment: @vmonteco is the second part inside a bash script?

Comment: @User965 You can, but you can also directly type it in your CLI.

Answer (score 1):

As far as renaming each file, most distributions have a `rename` command made just for that. If it's not already installed, it should be available via your package manager.

I've seen it work differently between distros, though. `man rename` for info on how your flavor works.